# Оббежав vs оббегав

Tags: орфография, недопустимая-метка

Всем доброго дня.
Возник вопрос (я не гуманитарий).
Как правильно писать слово - "оббежав" или (как предлагают всякие проверяльщики орфографии) - "оббегав"?
Пример: Я оббежав(оббегав) весь двор, уселся на завалинке.

---

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вы бежали по дороге. <=> You were running along the road. (эти предложения моделируют процесс)

Вы бегали по дороге. <=> You ran along the road. (эти предложения моделируют факт)

Comment: В русском языке некоторые глаголы моделируют процессы (например: бежать, идти, ползти, тащить), а некоторые глаголы моделируют факты (например: бегать, ходить, ползать, таскать).

Comment: Некоторые знатоки орфографии плохо разбираются в семантике.

Comment: Предлагаю Вам использовать глаголы "обежать" и "обегать" вместо буквосочетаний "оббежать" и "оббегать".

Comment: И как это будет выглядеть?  
Я обежать(обегать) весь двор, уселся на завалинке.
Получается как-то, как у дойчен золдатн, который есть плёх говорить по русски.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ГРАММАТИКА

В русском языке есть два глагола: бежать (направленное движение) и бегать (движение в разных направлениях или не в одно время).

Существует глагол обежать (сов. вид, нейтральный стиль) с тремя значениями.

ОБЕЖАТЬ, СВ. кого-что.1.Бегом обойти ВОКРУГ чего-л. О. вокруг дома. О. сад. О. кругом клумбы.2.Пробежать стороной, В ОБХОД чего-л., МИНУЯ что-л. Собака обежала его стороной. Как можно дальше обегаю глухой пустырь.3. Бегая, побывать ВСЮДУ, во многих местах, у всех, у многих. О. всех знакомых. О. все магазины.

Существуют глаголы обЕгать (сов. вид) и обегАть (несов. вид), которые соответствуют глаголу "бегать",  но это только одно значение "бегая, побывать всюду" и разговорный стиль: обЕгал вех друзей.

Приставка ОБ всем формам придает разговорный стиль. Её желательно заменить приставкой О (У Ожегова формы оббежать/оббегать вообще отсутствуют).

РЕШЕНИЕ

(1) Я, обежав весь двор, уселся на завалинке. Обежав - нейтральная форма, оббежав - разговорная форма. (2) Я, обегав весь двор, уселся на завалинке.Обегав - разговорная форма, оббегав также разговорная форма.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) Все вопросы к грамматике и толковым словарям, а не к орфографии.

2) Вообще говоря, оттенки смысла у глаголов разные. Обежать двор - это пробежать один круг, обегать - бегать долго, заглядывая в разные места. Поэтому, зная грамматику этой темы, можно доказать свою точку зрения, например: форма "обегать" больше подходит по смыслу и словарями не запрещается. А вот форму  "оббежать" можно покритиковать: почему используется приставка ОБ, снижающая стиль?

Comment: to: @София.
Значит варианты на существование могут быть такими:
*1.Я обежав весь двор, уселся на завалинке. (1 раз пробежал по периметру)
2.Я оббегав весь двор, уселся на завалинке. (хаотично, много раз.)*
Я всё правильно понял?

Comment: Предложение (1) верно. Для (2) лучше: Я обегав весь двор и ничего не найдя, уселся на завалинке. Форма разрешена словарями и, как представляется, больше подходит по смыслу, хотя "оббегав" тоже допускается.

Answer (score 0):

Тут все зависит от контекста. "Оббежав" уместнее будет сказать, если герой оббежал двор по периметру, и это уже совершенное действие. А "оббегав" - более общее и говорит о том, что герой долго и много бегал по двору в поисках чего-то.
Но, в принципе, уместны оба варианта - смотрите, какой Вам подойдут больше.